# (Sendgrid v3 API) How to build an API for sending emails to multiple recipients using a dynamic template?

Tags: email, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am trying to build an API in cURL to send an email to over 100,000+ recipients **separately**
(i.e. it should appear that I sent the mail to him personally). I will also be using a dynamic template, which would have 3 parameters to pass - `first_name`, `date`, & `city`. How should I build an API for the above idea in cURL? I am a beginner to APIs as well as cURL - that's why I am a bit confused

Also, I tried using the below code [(reference)](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/curl-examples#sending-a-basic-email-using-a-template), but I am not sure where I should put my `first_name`/`city`/`date` params - Can you guide me on this too?

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "recipient@example.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "sendeexampexample@example.com"},"subject":"Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain","value": "Heya!"}], "template_id" : "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID"}'
```

---

*I found out that a single API call can only support 1000 recipients - so in order to reach 100,000 people, I would do 100 such API calls (with 1000 recipients each).*

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you are sending template data you need to send it as part of the personalizations array, along with the relevant email address, under the key `dynamic_template_data`. For example:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [{"email": "recipient@example.com"}],
      "dynamic_template_data": { "first_name": "Phil" }
    }
  ],
  "from": {"email": "sendeexampexample@example.com"},
  "subject":"Hello, World!",
  "content": [{"type": "text/plain","value": "Heya!"}],
  "template_id" : "YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID"
}'
```

(Line breaks are added above for ease of reading.)

Check out this [documentation on sending emails with dynamic template data](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates) for more information.

Comment: Hi @philnash! Thanks for your reply! What if I want to send this email to multiple addresses (which would also have dynamic data for each address)?

Comment: The `personalizations` property is an array, so just add more objects with `to` addresses and their own `dynamic_template_data` to that array.